# My equations in putty, completely stumped

Tags: putty

I cannot for the life of me figure out what is wrong with these simple equations I have in putty. I think everything is set up right, but my output is wrong from my professors sample output by a slight degree.

```
//This program is used to calculate total cost of painting.
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

//These are the function prototypes that will be used for the main function.
void displayInstructions(int &feet, float &price);
float paintprice (int feet, float price);
float laborprice (int feet);
float totalcost(float paint, float labor);
void displayoutput (float paint, float labor, float total, int feet);

int main()
{
  int feet=0;
  float price=0;
  float paint=0;
  float labor=0;
  float total=0;

  displayInstructions(feet, paint);
  paint=paintprice(feet, paint);
  labor=laborprice(feet);
  total=totalcost(labor, paint);
  displayoutput(paint, labor, total, feet);
  return 0;
}

void displayInstructions(int &feet, float &price)
{
  cout<<setw(35)<<"==================================="<<endl;
  cout<<setw(30)<<"Painting Cost Calculator" <<endl;
  cout<<setw(35)<<"===================================" <<endl;
  cout<<"This program will compute the costs (paint, labor, total)\nbased on th\
e square feet of wall space to be painted \
and \nthe price of paint." <<endl;
 cout<<"How much wall space, in square feet, is going to be painted?" <<endl;
  cin>>feet;
  cout<<"How much is the price of a gallon of paint?" <<endl;
  cin>>price;
}

float paintprice (int feet, float price)
{
  float paint;
  paint=((feet/115)*price);
  return paint;
}

float laborprice (int feet)
{
  float labor;
  labor=((feet/115)*18*8);
  return labor;
}

float totalcost (float paint, float labor)
{
  float total;
  total=(paint+labor);
  return total;
}

void displayoutput (float paint, float labor, float total, int feet)
{
  cout<<"Square feet:" <<feet <<endl;
  cout<<"Paint cost:" <<paint <<endl;
  cout<<"Labor cost:" <<labor <<endl;
  cout<<"Total cost:" <<total <<endl;
}
```

based on the input being feet=12900, and price=12.00
The final output for the cost of paint should be $1346.09
The final output for the cost of labor should be $16153.04

I get respectively: $1344.00, $16128.00

if you can help me out it would be a life saver.

Comment: does  `labor=(((float)feet/115)*18*8); ` help? similarly with `paint =`

Comment: Yeah, it did, thanks. But what does this do and how does it fix my numbers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`labor=(((float)feet/115)*18*8);` Should fix your correctness issue. Similarly with `paint =`

The reason this works is because of the **way C++ calculations work**. When calculating an expression like a+b both are **automatically cast to a common type which is of most accuracy**.

However when you **divide integer by an integer**, as in `feet/115` the result is **calculated as an int** before assigning to the `float` value `labor`. This means that the **decimal places in that calculations are lost** and thus you lose your accuracy.

for e.g if feet = 120, the answer to `feet/115` would be 1, not 1.04.

An alternative way to fix this would be to **convert 115 to float** by writing 115.0f

Answer (score 0):

Your feet is an integer, when integer divides, it ignores numbers after decimal point
e.g `int a = 10;`  a/3 = 3 not 3.33333333.  The (float) cast your int to float so it works.